# What is the return type of iter_errors() of jsonchema?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am having the below code to validate a json file against a json schema file. I am using the jsonschema library for this and im using the below code snippet (Python 2.7).

Even though the json parsing passes the schema validation, the flow goes to the else block and increment the counter there instead of the going to the if block.

Note: I am splitting up an big json file, which has an array of objects, into a single json file which just one array element, before hitting my below code.

```py
validate_schema = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(json.loads(schema_data))
            errors = validate_schema.iter_errors(json.loads(json_rec))
            if not errors:
                print 'no errors......................'
                valid_rec_ctr += 1
            else:
                invalid_rec_ctr += 1
                error_msg = ''
                issue_tag = "griefs_" + str(rec_ctr)
                record_tag = "record_"+ str(rec_ctr)
                grief[record_tag] = json_rec
                for error in sorted(errors, key=str):
                    # print error.message, "at ", error.path
                    error_msg = error_msg + str(error.message) + " at" + str(error.path) + '^^^'
                print '\r\n'
                grief[issue_tag] = error_msg
```

Why the error iterable object is being created even if the validation is successful?

Comment: The return type is a collections.Iterable of jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationErrors `print(errors)` and let's see what that looks like. May also help to `print(type(errors))`

Comment: @JacobIRR json has 3 records, split into 3 small jsons, runs the validation for each. first 2 jsons have errors, the 3rd is clean. But below is the result of `print errors` and `print type(errors)`

`<generator object iter_errors at 0x0000000003BE9BD0>
<type 'generator'>
u'string1234' is too long
<generator object iter_errors at 0x0000000003BE9C60>
<type 'generator'>
u'string1234' is too long
<generator object iter_errors at 0x0000000003BE9BD0>
<type 'generator'>`

Why the error object is created even if there are no errors for the 3rd json???

Comment: The empty collection may be "truthy" so checking `if not errors` may not be enough. You could try checking `if not len(errors)` which would help confirm that the empty collection has items in it.